# Crear una secuencia en un tipo complejo en XML y validarla contra un esquema

Tags: xml

¿Cómo pongo varias repeticiones de los elementos que forman parte de una secuencia que está dentro de un tipo complejo?

Tengo el siguiente esquema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  <xs:element name="Measurements">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>Schema for Measurements data transmission</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="m_doc" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="m_parameters">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="m_name" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="m_isEngValue" type="xs:boolean"/>
              <xs:element name="m_unit" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="m_radix" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="m_value" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Y pruebo con el siguiente XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Measurements xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
    <m_doc>TestDoc</m_doc>
    <m_parameters>

      <!-- Primer grupo -->
      <m_name>Length</m_name>
      <m_isEngValue>false</m_isEngValue>
      <m_unit></m_unit>
      <m_radix>HEXADECIMAL</m_radix>
      <m_value>0</m_value>

      <!-- Segundo grupo -->
      <m_name>Height</m_name>
      <m_isEngValue>false</m_isEngValue>
      <m_unit></m_unit>
      <m_radix>DECIMAL</m_radix>
      <m_value>0</m_value>

    </m_parameters>
</Measurements>
```

Obteniendo el error:

> Cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid Content Was Found Starting With
>   Element 'm_name'. No Child Element Is Expected At This Point., Line
>   '13', Column '15'.

Ese error se corresponde al segundo grupo 5 elementos que constituyen un parámetro. Si quito ese segundo grupo entonces no tengo error.

Estoy probando con un validador online : [www.freeformatter.com](https://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html)

El esquema es un requisito sobre el que no tengo control y estoy obligado a respetar. Tengo que hacer XML que se ajuste a ese esquema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El esquema en tu pregunta no permite ninguna repetición de elementos porque ni el elemento `xs:sequence` ni uno de los elementos `xs:element` lleva los atributos `minOccurs`/`maxOccurs`. Esto significa que el esquema solo permite la secuencia completa, y solo una vez.

Si pudieses cambiar `<xs:sequence>` a `<xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#declare-contentModel), podrías repetir toda la secuencia tantas veces como quisieras. Además podrías permitir por ejemplo 10 repeticiones con `<xs:sequence maxOccurs="10">`.

El elemento `xs:element` también permite añadir los dos atributos (https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#declare-element).

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Martin. Voy a editar mi pregunta para aclarar que el esquema me viene dato y no lo puedo cambiar. Tengo que hacer un XML que se ajuste al esquema.

Comment: Vale, pero en tu pregunta también explicaste "Si quito ese segundo grupo entonces no tengo error", es decir, ya sabes qué hacer para crear un documento válido. Este esquema no da ninguna opción para repetir elementos.

Comment: Tienes razón, se cómo hacer un documento válido con un elemento. Pero no se cómo hacer un documento válido con dos elementos, o tres o cuatro que se ajuste a ese esquema. Tu comentario me hace pensar que no es posible. ¿Entonces <xs:sequence> permite solo un elemento? Si es así eso sí responde a mi pregunta.

Comment: `xs:sequence` sin atributos `minOccurs` y `maxOccurs` solo permite exactamente la secuencia de elementos dados, sin repeticiones. Se puede también poner estos atributos en `xs:element` pero el esquema dado no lo tiene, por eso no permite repetir elementos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, edita tu respuesta con ese texto y podré aceptarla.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos, acabo de editar la respuesta para adaptarla a tus aclaraciones de la pregunta.